# Find a power series representation of $\cosh(\sqrt{x})$. Determine also the radius of convergence and interval of convergence.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

The problem that was given was to use integration to find a power series representation of the following function $\cosh(\sqrt{x})$. I know how to find the some easy power series representations of something like $\frac{1}{1-x}$ but the $\cosh(\sqrt{x})$  is throwing me off. I assume I have to integrate the function first then what?

Comment: Do you know the MacLaurin series for $\cosh(y)$?

Comment: Find the power series for $\cosh$ then substitute $x$ with $\sqrt{x}$ in it (half the powers).

Comment: @user10354138 yes

Answer (score 0):

Like proposed in the comments, you can drop $\sqrt x$ into the McLaurin series of $\cosh$:
$$\begin{align}
\cosh(\sqrt x) &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(2n)!} \\
&= 1 + \frac{x}{2\cdot1} + \frac{x^2}{4\cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot1} +\cdots
\end{align}$$
This is fine over $\Bbb C$.  Depending on the chosen branch cut of the square root we have that the $\varphi$-coordinate in polar coordinates is only determined modulo $\pi i$:

$$x = |x| \,\exp(i\arg x + 2k \pi i)$$
with some integer $k\in \Bbb Z$. Thus
$$\sqrt x = {\textstyle\sqrt{|x|} } \, \exp(\tfrac i2\arg x + k \pi i)$$

Now $\cosh$ is $2\pi i$-periodic so that $\cosh(\sqrt{x})$ is well defined.

---

Over $\Bbb R$ however, the situation is more complicated: $\sqrt x$ is *not defined* for negative $x$, so that the function is
$$\begin{align}
f: \Bbb R^{\geqslant 0} &\to \Bbb R^{\geqslant 0} \\
x &\mapsto \cosh(\sqrt x)
\end{align}$$
and $\Bbb R^{\geqslant 0}$ is the maxmial preimage.  This means that $f$ is analytic in every $x_0 \in \Bbb R^{\geqslant 0}$, and the radius of convergence when expanded around $x_0$ is $x_0$.  Getting the explicit Taylor coefficients $a_n=a_n(x0)$ when expanded at $x_0$ is not an easy exercise, though.